# Error Angular Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined at bootstrap

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfcXU.png)

when doing ng serve to run my project I am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ng-bootstrap` then uninstall and install it again

```
npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --save
```

then

```
npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --save
```

also, be sure that you imported the

```
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
```

in the subject **Module.ts** file (probably `app.Module.ts`)

as well as mentioned in the imports array

```
  imports: [
    ...
    NgbModule,
    ...
  ],
```

**However,** if you are using the traditional bootstrap be sure you did put the related `@import` statement in `styles.css` file
Example

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying doing an `npm install bootstrap` again. Maybe there was an issue that occurred during the `npm` installation